# Algorithm to calculate the optimum number of items to fetch

Tags: python, algorithm

Alright here's a question that's eating me from inside so any help is appreciated. 
I have a web service that returns a list of items. The number of items returned is governed by two variables 'page' and 'per_page'. So a URL like

```
abc.com?page=10&per_page=100
```

Will show the 10th page with 100 items in it. I have to query this service efficiently and only get items that were added after the last fetch. So say I have cached all the items upto #1024 and then 12 more items were added to it making the count 1036.
How do I calculate the page and per_page value so that I get all the added items in a  single page while keeping the per_page qunatity to be as close to the newly added items as possible. For eg: in this case the per_page should be as close to but no less than 12. I already know the last count of cache and the current total number of items. Its okay if the fetched page has the previously cached items. I am trying to find the most optimum response and not the most accurate. The language I am using is python but just an algorithm or psuedo-code would be very welcome.

Note: the service gives me the earliest items first. So the latest entries are always added to the last page

Comment: `per_page=16&page=64` I think would be ideal for this case ... but no idea  yet on an algorithm to use

Comment: I am looking for an optimum algorithm. I rememebr doing these kinds of greedy algo problems in school but its all out of my systme now :)

Answer (score 2):

Is there a compelling reason to not over-request?

`abc.com?page=2&per_page=1024`

Just always set `page=2` and `per_page` = number of items cached.

The only weird case is when the number of added elements is greater than the number of items cached, in which case you have to `abc.com?page=1&per_page=99999`

Comment: The server may have a limit on `per_page`, which may not be documented in the API… but this is certainly worth trying. The worst case is that there's a race and a whole slew of new items got added that you weren't expecting and now you have to process them… but I'm pretty sure you actually _want_ to process them in that case anyway…

Comment: The reason I want the items requested to be minimal is due to the nature of service. The more items you request the more time it takes. So I have to find the optimal number and get all the items in a single page

Comment: Plus now that I have formulated the problem I am dying to solve it. I have spent my morning going over it :)

Comment: this is a pretty clever solution actually :) at least thats my 2c

Comment: I'd check to see if my solution is fast.  Maybe the time depends on how many items are returned, not requested.

Comment: @QuestionC I would imagine it to be fast (assuming you dont have to go back to page 1 for some reason :P)

Comment: I have and its very slow. Hence my requiremnt for an optimally small number. And also for my own sanity :)

Answer (score 2):

so start with the knowledge that you need to have `per_page` at least equal to the number of new items (assuming you want them all on the same page)

```
 def items_per_page(total_item_count,new_item_count):
     for i in itertools.count(new_item_count):
        if total_items % i>= new_item_count:
            return i
 total_count = 136  #including the new items
 new_count = 12
 ct_per_page = items_per_page(total_count,new_count)
 page_num = total_count//ct_per_page  + 1 # the last page
 print my_url+"?page="+page_num+"&per_page="+ct_per_page
```

at least im pretty sure that will always give you an optimal result :)

by optimal I mean the minimal value for `per_page`

Comment: Is the total_count the count with additional items added. Also I think the page_num should be (total_count//ct_per_page)+1 to get the last page.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code with a small bug-fix to give the most optimal page size (the suggested code wouldn't return a page size that exactly divides the total count).

```
def items_per_page(total_item_count,new_item_count):
     for i in itertools.count(new_item_count):
        if total_items % i>= new_item_count or total_items %i == 0:
            return i
 total_count = 136  #including the new items
 new_count = 12
 ct_per_page = items_per_page(total_count,new_count)
 page_num = total_count//ct_per_page  + 1 # the last page
 print my_url+"?page="+page_num+"&per_page="+ct_per_page
```